# How to unbind all previously added events from the 'scroll' event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

How can I unbind all the functions that I previously added to the `scroll` event?  I want to do this without using the names of the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to unbind everything from scroll event:
`$(window).unbind("scroll");`

Or substitute specific elements for `window` if you don't want to unbind everything

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#your-element').off('scroll');
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks, @DaniP!! Updated.

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately that did not unbind any events from the scroll event for me